# SSRS Comma-delimited list as Parameter value with "N" character

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssms, sql-server-profiler

I have entire script in `SSMS` (I'm using the version 2014) and there I use parameter `@EmployeeID` which contains hundreds of `Employee_ID (int, not null)`.
If I choose only 1 `Employee_ID`, then is OK, but if I choose more `Employee_ID`, then is problem. 
I used google and I created function, which creates separate lines from a single string of several numbers. 
Function works like this - I run:

```sql
SELECT * FROM dbo.GetDelimitedValues('1,2,3,4',',')
```

and I get 4 rows - first row with value 1, second row with value 2 etc, but I traced my attempt in SQL Profiler, because I wanted to see what run SSRS and I was surprised.

My problem:

In `SSMS` I have this `where`:

```sql
WHERE c.empID  IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.GetDelimitedValues(@EmployeeID ,','))
```

And SQL Profiler showed me this:

```sql
WHERE c.empID  IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.GetDelimitedValues(N''6525152'',N''1453'',N''6525236'',N''2349'')
```

And I don't know what means that character `"N"`? And why I don't have something like:

`dbo.GetDelimitedValues('6525152,1453,6525236,2349',',')` - because this form will be ok for my table valued function.

What would you recommend me to edit or add or delete?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `N''` means a unicode string (`nvarchar`)

Comment: Also, if you are passing in a multi-value parameter from SSRS conating your list of employees, you do not need your function, you can just do 'WHERE c.empID IN (@EmployeeID)` and SSRS will parse this correctly